# Objective-C how long does an address last?

Tags: c++, objective-c

In the past my code has incurred run-time errors where I'm trying to check to see if an object exists and I get messages along the lines of "EXC_BAD_ACCESS tried to access freed object". So- suppose I have a class which exposes a pointer to an internal Boolean variable which is YES for the lifetime of the object, and switched No when the object deallocates:

```
@implementation TestClass

- (id) init {

        //instance variables.
        amIAlive = YES;
        alivePointer = &amIAlive;
        return self;

}

- (BOOL *)getSignal {
        return alivePointer;
}

- (void) dealloc {
        NSLog(@"Test Object is deallocing");
        amIAlive = NO;
        [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Now, using this class I try this.

```
TestObject *obj = [[TestObject alloc] init];
BOOL *signal = [obj getSignal];

    if(*signal) {
    NSLog(@"Test Object is still alive");
    }

[obj release];

    if(!*signal) {
    NSLog(@"Test Object has been dealloced");
    }
```

Voila, it works as expected. Now, here's the thing. I'm not naive enough to take for granted that the address occupied by "amIAlive" won't get reassigned to some other object at some point after the object deallocates. However, I'm still pointing to that address with my "*signal" outside of the instance of TestObject. When the address gets reassigned, "*signal" will have unpredictable results. How long can I rely on the address to amIAlive? Is there a way to "lock" that address down so that I can always rely on it? Thanks for your time!

Comment: An address lasts until something else is stored in its place -- potentially "forever".  But what the address *points to* can go "poof" quite unexpectedly, if you haven't observed the somewhat arcane rules for Objective-C reference counting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Locking" that address would mean that it would never been returned by malloc/alloc again.

This is tantamount to saying that whatever smallest unit of storage it points to is now inaccessible.

If that's what you want, then why deallocate in the first place? Your question implies that you want "memory leaks", ie: stuff that stays kind-of-alive even though deallocated.

Untested idea #1: try a "malloc(1)" right after your dealloc. Odds are that you could get lucky and have malloc grab the memory that was just freed my dealloc.

Untested idea #2: have a field in `TestClass` that is pointer to whatever it is that you want to survive dealloc, and, during dealloc, transfer 'ownership' of that field to some other object whose purpose it to monitor/keep track of your "leaks:"

But an explanation as to *why* you want to do that (except for debugging purposes) would probably go a long way to start thinking about a real solution to something that, at first, doesn't look like a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Once the object is freed, the object can no longer reply to the message. Its gone. The memory could now be used by a completely different object.

The second example works because you've passed in the pointer to init, the memory that pointer points to is still allocated for that BOOL.

Answer (score 0):

Add a WeakReference to that object to a global array.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a couple of problems.

In your init you return self, but self does not yet exist. You'll need:

```
-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // do your init stuff
    }
    return self;
}
```

When dealloc'ed there is no way to access your object anymore.

How have you declared the iAmAlive variable? Why do you access it using a pointer and not just directly? I recommend you read up on [Memory Management](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html).

Comment: `self` does exist before you call `[super init]`.

Comment: while self exists, you _need_ `self = [super init];` in a proper init method.